# Opponents health not decreasing, and turns not flipping over

Tags: python, python-2.7

So, for the main action sequence of my game, I have this code for the battle. It works, sort of. I can choose the moves and all the text will display, but it doesn't take health off of the opponent, and the turn doesn't change over. I can't for the life of me figure out what I've done wrong. Here is the code:
I'm using python 2.7.

```
    play_again = True
            while play_again is True:
              winner = None
              player_health = 100
              computer_health = random.randrange(1,200)

              player_turn = True
              computer_turn = False

              while (player_health != 0 or computer_health != 0):

                heal_up = False
                miss = False

                moves = {"Punch": random.randint(18, 25),
                         "Slap": random.randint(10, 35),
                         "Kick": random.randint(10, 25)}
                if player_turn is True:
                  print("""1. Punch
                           2. Slap
                           3. Kick
""")
                  player_move = raw_input(">>> ")

                  move_miss = random.randint(1,10)
                  if move_miss == 1:
                    miss = True
                  else:
                    miss = False

                  if miss:
                    player_move = 0 
                    print("You missed!")
                  else:
                    if player_move in ("1", "punch"):
                      player_move = moves["Punch"]
                      print("You used Punch! It dealt %s damage!") % player_move
                    elif player_move in ("2", "slap"):
                      player_move = moves["Slap"]
                      print("\nYou used Slap!. It dealt %s damage.") % player_move
                    elif player_move in ("3", "kick"):
                      player_move = moves["Kick"]
                      print("\nYou used Kick! It dealt %s damage.") % player_move
                    else:
                       print("\nThat is not a valid move. Please try again.")

                else:

                  move_miss = random.randint(0, 10)
                  if move_miss == 1:
                    miss = True
                  else:
                    miss = False

                  if miss:
                    computer_move = 0
                    print('The Opponent Missed!')
                  else:
                    imoves = ["Punch", "Slap","Kick"]
                    imoves = random.choice(imoves)
                    CPU_move = moves[imoves]
                    if CPU_move == moves["Punch"]:
                        print("The opponent used Punch. It dealt %s Damage.") % CPU_move
                        player_health -= CPU_move
                    if CPU_move == moves["Slap"]:
                        print("\nThe opponent used Slap. It dealt %s Damage.") % CPU_move
                        player_health -= CPU_move
                    if CPU_move == moves["Kick"]:
                        print("\nThe opponent used Kick. It dealt %s Damage.") % CPU_move
                        player_health -= CPU_move


              if player_turn is true:
                computer_health -= player_move
                if computer_health <= 0:
                    computer_health = 0
                    winner = "Player"
                    break
              else:
                if player_health <= 0:
                    player_health = 0
                    winner = "Computer"
                    break

              print("Your health: %s, Opponents health: %s") % (player_health, computer_health)

              # switch turns
              player_turn = not player_turn
              computer_turn = not computer_turn

              if winner == "Player":
                print("Your health: %s, Opponents health: %s") % (player_health, computer_health)
                print('Congratulations! You have won.')
              else:
                print("Your health: %s, Opponents health: %s") % (player_health, computer_health)
                print("Sorry, but your opponent wiped the floor with you. Better luck next time.")
```

Comment: are you sure it runs? the `t` in `true` needs to be caps: `if player_turns is True`.
a better way to write is to remove `is True`: `while play_again` and `if player_turn`.

Comment: Whoops, totally missed that typo. Have fixed that, but the turn still won't change over and health does not decrease.

Comment: also need to move the `)` outside in `print("You used Punch! It dealt %s damage!") % player_move`, as in `print("You used Punch! It dealt %s damage!" % player_move)`

Comment: and change the `while` condition to `and`. `or` will keep the game running as long as one party hasn't hit 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your entire code that deals with decreasing the opponent's health and flipping the turns are improperly indented to be inside the outer loop (which checks if the player wants to play again) instead of the inner loop (which is the main loop that actually plays each turn).

Simply indent that code with two more spaces, and fix your typo of `True` in `if player_turn is true:` (the first letter of `True` has to be capitalized), and your code would work:

```
import random
play_again = True
while play_again is True:
  winner = None
  player_health = 100
  computer_health = random.randrange(1,200)

  player_turn = True
  computer_turn = False

  while (player_health != 0 or computer_health != 0):

    heal_up = False
    miss = False

    moves = {"Punch": random.randint(18, 25),
             "Slap": random.randint(10, 35),
             "Kick": random.randint(10, 25)}
    if player_turn is True:
      print("""1. Punch
               2. Slap
               3. Kick""")
      player_move = raw_input(">>> ")

      move_miss = random.randint(1,10)
      if move_miss == 1:
        miss = True
      else:
        miss = False

      if miss:
        player_move = 0
        print("You missed!")
      else:
        if player_move in ("1", "punch"):
          player_move = moves["Punch"]
          print("You used Punch! It dealt %s damage!") % player_move
        elif player_move in ("2", "slap"):
          player_move = moves["Slap"]
          print("\nYou used Slap!. It dealt %s damage.") % player_move
        elif player_move in ("3", "kick"):
          player_move = moves["Kick"]
          print("\nYou used Kick! It dealt %s damage.") % player_move
        else:
           print("\nThat is not a valid move. Please try again.")

    else:

      move_miss = random.randint(0, 10)
      if move_miss == 1:
        miss = True
      else:
        miss = False

      if miss:
        computer_move = 0
        print('The Opponent Missed!')
      else:
        imoves = ["Punch", "Slap","Kick"]
        imoves = random.choice(imoves)
        CPU_move = moves[imoves]
        if CPU_move == moves["Punch"]:
            print("The opponent used Punch. It dealt %s Damage.") % CPU_move
            player_health -= CPU_move
        if CPU_move == moves["Slap"]:
            print("\nThe opponent used Slap. It dealt %s Damage.") % CPU_move
            player_health -= CPU_move
        if CPU_move == moves["Kick"]:
            print("\nThe opponent used Kick. It dealt %s Damage.") % CPU_move
            player_health -= CPU_move


    if player_turn is True:
      computer_health -= player_move
      if computer_health <= 0:
          computer_health = 0
          winner = "Player"
          break
    else:
      if player_health <= 0:
          player_health = 0
          winner = "Computer"
          break

    print("Your health: %s, Opponents health: %s") % (player_health, computer_health)

    # switch turns
    player_turn = not player_turn
    computer_turn = not computer_turn

  if winner == "Player":
    print("Your health: %s, Opponents health: %s") % (player_health, computer_health)
    print('Congratulations! You have won.')
  else:
    print("Your health: %s, Opponents health: %s") % (player_health, computer_health)
    print("Sorry, but your opponent wiped the floor with you. Better luck next time.")
```

Here's a sample output with the fix:

```
1. Punch
               2. Slap
               3. Kick
>>> 2

You used Slap!. It dealt 34 damage.
Your health: 100, Opponents health: 59

The opponent used Slap. It dealt 31 Damage.
Your health: 69, Opponents health: 59
1. Punch
               2. Slap
               3. Kick
>>> 1
You used Punch! It dealt 21 damage!
Your health: 69, Opponents health: 38
The Opponent Missed!
Your health: 69, Opponents health: 38
1. Punch
               2. Slap
               3. Kick
>>> 1
You used Punch! It dealt 19 damage!
Your health: 69, Opponents health: 19

The opponent used Kick. It dealt 19 Damage.
Your health: 50, Opponents health: 19
1. Punch
               2. Slap
               3. Kick
>>> 1
You used Punch! It dealt 22 damage!
Your health: 50, Opponents health: 0
Congratulations! You have won.
1. Punch
               2. Slap
               3. Kick
>>>
```

Comment: Thanks, I did this, but the turn still doesn't flip over for some reason...

Comment: I just updated my answer with a sample output from my test run. If you aren't getting something similar, you should double check your indentation again, or simply copy and paste my code above.

Comment: Yep, thanks, figured it out.